# How do I remap the mouse clicks so that a previously held down key carries on sending inputs once I release the remapped key?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, autohotkey

Let me explain my scenario.

I'm holding down the 1 key producing a string of 1's. When I right or left click my mouse, the string of 1's stop briefly before resuming once again to produce a string of 1's inputs. The 1 key has been pressed and held down once throughout this.

The problem occurs when I remap the left and right mouse clicks to a key on the keyboard; this is what happens.

I'm once again holding down the 1 key producing a string of 1's. When I press the remapped key the string of 1's stop and the mouse left / right clicks as intended, however, once I release the remapped key the string of 1's do not continue like in the first scenario. This means that I would have to repress and hold the 1 key in order to start the string of 1's again.

Question: How do I remap the mouse clicks to a key so that the string of 1's continues afterwards once I release the remapped key?

Answer (score 0):

In AutoHotKey you would need to poll the keys that are down when you release your remapped key then re-press it virtually.

Two versions, one simple, one complex:

Simple version checks for keys that are physically down on release and just re-presses them

```
keysOfInterest := ["a","b","c",...]    ; list of keys

LButton::
  ; Do a thing
return

LButton Up::
  ; Do an un-thing
  for index, element in keysOfInterest
  {
    if GetKeyState(element,"P") ; key is physically down.
      SendInput {%element% up}{%element% down}; re-press it
  }
return
```

Complex version that tracks if a key was physically down BEFORE your remapped key got pressed. If it was pressed during your remap press, it doesn't react.

```
keysOfInterest := ["a","b","c",...]    ; list of keys
keyTrackOne   := [0,0,0,...]          ; track their state at key-down

LButton:: ; Key-down
  for index, element in keysOfInterest ; cycle through keys of interest
  {
    if GetKeyState(element,"P")       ; key is currently down
      keyTrackOne[index] := 1         ; mark it as 
  }
  ; Do a thing
return

LButton up::
  for index, element in keyTrackOne
  {
    if (element == 1) && GetKeyState(keysOfInterest[index],"P")
      SendInput {%keysOfInterest[index]% Up}{%keysOfInterest[index]% Down}; re-press it
  }
  ; Do an un-thing
return
```

Comment: See my comment, it wouldn't let me post the script in the comment.

Comment: I'm finding that the string of 1's do not continue with the first example, it only adds 1 extra 1 at the end instead of keeping it held down.